# Is a final collection thread safe in multicore system?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

i have a student question:

i would like to have an advice and some explanation about visibility problem in multicore **if there is one**.

I use Registry pattern in my SpringBoot Application to map different scanners instances to their names.

**Configuration:**

```
@Bean
public WebScannerExecutor webScannerExecutor(final WebScannerClientProcessor webScannerClientProcessor) {
    return new WebScannerExecutor(webScannerClientProcessor);
}

@Bean
public TLSScannerExecutor tlsScannerExecutor(final @Value("${tls.scanner.path}") String path, final BashProcessor bashProcessor) {
    return new TLSScannerExecutor(path, bashProcessor);
}

@Bean
public ScanExecuterRegistry executerRegistry(final WebScannerExecutor webScannerExecutor, final TLSScannerExecutor tlsScannerExecutor) {
    final ScanExecuter[] arr = new ScanExecuter[] {webScannerExecutor, tlsScannerExecutor};
    return new ScanExecuterRegistry(arr);
}
```

**Registry:**

```
public class ScanExecuterRegistry {

private final ImmutableMap<ScannerType, ScanExecuter> registry;

 public ScanExecuterRegistry(final ScanExecuter... executors) {
        this.registry = ImmutableMap.<ScannerType, ScanExecuter> builder().putAll(Arrays.asList(executors).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(ScanExecuter::getType, e -> e))).build();
    }
```

Right now i am using ImmutableMap from Guava and i am pretty sure there is no problem. But...

```
private final Map<ScannerType, ScanExecuter> registry;
```

If i take instead of ImmutableMap just a final map (immutable reference but not content), could any problem rise? Any problem with thread caches, visibility et cetera in multicore systems (even with the usage of singeltons)?

**EDITED:**

> All good as long as you don't modify the content

Exactly that i would like to get explained. I am not so good with java memory model yet.

I can change the content of map, only in spring configuration class adding a new scanner. So the application will restart in any case. Can there still be a problem?

Comment: All good as long as you don't modify the content, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457109/java-concurrency-is-final-field-initialized-in-constructor-thread-safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure that a variable shared in a multithread environment doesn't cause errors you need to ensure that:

- The variable is immutable or
- The variable is mutable, but the access to that variable is synchronized or
- The variable is mutable, but you don't change its value after creating it (*).

If you replace an `ImmutableMap` with a mutable `Map` (for example an `HashMap`) all works if that `Map` is not muted after it is shared between threads.

Note that defining a variable as `final` doesn't ensure that its content never change. `final`, for objects, means only that the reference can't be changed, but it is possible for example to add, remove or change items to a `final` `Map`.

---

(*) Note: as explained by @bowmore it is necessarely to guarantee a [safe publication](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_safe_publication) of the shared variable:

> **Safe publication** makes all the values written before the publication visible to all readers that observed the published object

This can be done with:

- Initializing an object reference from a `static` initializer.
- Storing a reference to it into a `volatile` field.
- Storing a reference to it into a `final` field.
- Storing a reference to it into a field that is properly guarded by a (`synchronized`) lock.

Comment: Good answer, but you must also ensure the mutable variable is published safely.

Comment: @bowmore I edited my answer to show the possible ways to safely publish a mutable variable